# I need to move everything in a directory to a folder in the same directory

Tags: batch-file

Basically i need to do this, move everything in the D:\ disk to a folder in the same disk.
I have tried:

```
MOVE D:\ D:\folder
```

But it fails because D:\folder its also part of D:\

D:\folder does not exist before, its created by the same script one line before and only if it doesn't exist like this:

```
IF EXIST D:\folder\NUL GOTO continue
MKDIR D:\folder
MOVE D:\ D:\folder
:continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MOVE D:\*.* D:\folder` to move all files (but no folders). If you specify a folder as source then `MOVE` renames that folder.

If you need to move all folders as well, you can use

```
for /d %%D in (*) do if /I %%D NEQ %targetfolder% move %%D %targetfolder%
```

Finally, have a look at `robocopy` which was made for tasks like this.